# Getting exception while deleting object from navigation property in one to many relationship entityframework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using EF code first in my project. The POCO classes and fluent api are as follows:

**POCO classes**

```
public class Tenant
{
  public int TenantId { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
} 

public class Service
{
  public int ServiceId { get; set; }

  public int TenantId { get; set; }
  public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent Api**

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
               .HasMany(p => p.Services)
               .WithRequired(p => p.Tenant)
               .HasForeignKey(p => p.TenantId)
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The relationship between Tenant and Service is 1 to many bidirectional. When i am trying to delete Service from the list of services like this:

```
  tenantProvider.Tenant.Services.Remove(service);
```

I got this exception:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Can anybody please me out and tell me what i am doing wrong ??
 (Because of other relationships in my schema and multiple cascade path i have to set cascade delete false)

**Edit**

The answer given by *@Kirill Bestemyanov* solved my issue and now i can successfully delete the service from *Service* table. But still i don't understand why i was getting the above mentioned exception when i was trying to delete the service from *Services* navigation property of *Tenant* entity. Can anyone please explain me briefly ??

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with this - **tenantProvider.DeleteObject(service)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete service instead of removing it from navigation property collection:

```
tenantProvider.Set<Service>.Remove(service);
```

**Update**

`tenantProvider.Tenant.Services.Remove(service);` removes your service entity from navigation property collection but not removes this entity from db. It removes link (that is in foreign key value).

Comment: +1 your answer worked but can you please explain me why `tenantProvider.Tenant.Services.Remove(service);` is not working and why the error is coming ??

Comment: I think object creation and deletion in EF must be called from the context itself (i.e. ObjectContext or DbContext) to mark the object as new or delete. Until you call SaveChanges(), it will be eventually saved to the database. [DbContext.Set<T>().Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679171(v=vs.113).aspx) - [ObjectContext.DeleteObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.deleteobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: tenantProvider.Tenant.Services.Remove(service); removes your service from navigation property collection but not removes this entity from db. So after that you have entity service with null in foreign key column.